# MochaUI Window loading ASPX page in Iframe and commuunicating with window?

Tags: asp.net, mootools

I am hoping someone has experience with this, but I am loading a window from a link on my main page. The window loads an ASPX page via the window’s loadmethod of iFrame.  The aspx page has its own update panel on it and I was wondering how I can call the window’s “spinner” / process indicator while the page is processing. I have looked at the documentation on some online information about it but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the spinner this is what I do:

```
function getMochaWindow(windowId) {
    return MochaUI.Windows.instances.get(windowId);
}

function showLoading(winEl) {
    getMochaWindow(winEl.id).showSpinner(winEl.getElement('.mochaSpinner'));
}
```

You need to call showLoading() passing the window element where you want it to appear.